# How to check in Laravel, if a table is completly empty, BEFORE do anything

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanna quest if there is a method to check if one model table is empty, before doing anything. I have inside my seeder class a method to generate fake entries inside the database. But before i call this method, i wanna be sure that nothing inside my 'company' table. The thing is most people give example like: Company::where(...). I don't wanna use a where, because i don't wanna find anything specific inside the table. I only wanna return a null or a zero without error to handle the value and call after this my insert method for seeding the database. Thank you very much

Comment: can u try first ..?

Comment: I tried to write inside laravel queries like: DB::table('company)->(DB::raw('select count(*)'). but if there are no entries inside the table, i can't handle the returning value ( saying if ( .... == 0 or ... == null ) -> returns an syntax error

Comment: i used too this command: DB::table('company')->select(DB::raw('select count(1) from client where id=1)')), but there is a problem too ...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries -> Aggregates section specifically shows an example of exactly what you are looking for. Usually API documents such as this, is the best place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like that without any **where** condition

```
$count = \DB::table('company')->count();
if($count == 0) {
   //add fake data...
}else {
  //data already there no need to add fake data
}
```